# Access variable outside of opencv callback fuction

Tags: python, opencv, variables, callback, scope

I'm using OpenCV to track one part of an image according to its RGB values and using a `cv2.setMouseCallback`

Here's my code:

```
def track_ground():
    b_min, g_min, r_min = 255, 255, 255
    b_max, g_max, r_max = 0, 0, 0
    
    ##########################################
    # mouse callback function
    def get_pixel(event,x,y,flags,param):

        if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
            b, g, r = img[x, y]
            # We are moving around the mouse to find the range of values for rgb
            # of the background; we will use them for thresholding later.

            b_min = min(b, b_min)
            g_min = min(g, g_min)
            r_min = min(r, r_min)
            b_max = max(b, b_max)
            g_max = max(g, g_max)
            r_max = max(r, r_max)

    
    img = cv2.imread('data/my_image.jpg')
    cv2.namedWindow('image')
    cv2.setMouseCallback('image',get_pixel)
    while True:
        cv2.imshow('image',img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
    ###########################################
    
    print('min:', b_min, g_min, r_min)
    print('max:', b_max, g_max, r_max)
    
    return (b_min, g_min, r_min), (b_max, g_max, r_max)
```

The idea is that i want to get minimun and maximum value R, G, B pixels for variables `b_min`, `g_min`, `r_min`, `b_max`, `g_max`, `r_max` while i'm moving my mouse around a specific part of the image. For that i'm using 'cv2.setMouseCallback`and the callback function`get_pixel` which should keep the minimum/maximum values of RGB pixel at point x, y position of the moving mouse.

Now there is an error related to variable accessibility outside of the callback function that says:
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'b_min' referenced before assignment`.

How can i access and modify those variables ?

Comment: you need to learn about python's "nonlocal" keyword

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz actually that is the elegant answer i'm looking for. you should put it on answer so i can accept it.

Comment: if I post an answer containing a single sentence, the ruling class will crucify me because rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the  bgr minmax variables outside of the function, and used them within the scope of the `track_ground` and `get_pixel` functions using the `global` keyword. I also changed your display code to only show the image once, print the min max values when the window is open, and end the while loop when "X" is pressed on the window.

Code:

```
import cv2

def track_ground():
    b_min, g_min, r_min = 255, 255, 255
    b_max, g_max, r_max = 0, 0, 0
    
    ##########################################
    # mouse callback function
    def get_pixel(event,x,y,flags,param):
        nonlocal b_min, g_min, r_min, b_max, g_max, r_max

        if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
            b, g, r = img[x, y]
            # We are moving around the mouse to find the range of values for rgb
            # of the background; we will use them for thresholding later.

            b_min = min(b, b_min)
            g_min = min(g, g_min)
            r_min = min(r, r_min)
            b_max = max(b, b_max)
            g_max = max(g, g_max)
            r_max = max(r, r_max)

    
    img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
    cv2.namedWindow('image')
    cv2.setMouseCallback('image',get_pixel)
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    while cv2.getWindowProperty('image', 1) >= 0:
        print(b_min, g_min, r_min)
        print(b_max, g_max, r_max)
        k = cv2.waitKey(30)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
    
    ###########################################
    return (b_min, g_min, r_min), (b_max, g_max, r_max)

print(track_ground())
```

I tested it on this image and it seemed to work:[image]

Comment: @moctarjallo Sorry for not responding, I didn't see your comment. I agree that ```global``` shouldn't have been used. I have edited the code to use the ```nonlocal``` keyword.

Comment: Great. This is the solution i also used after @Christoph Rackwitz 's solution in a comment to my question above. I'm still going to accept your code!

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use the `param` parameter to `get_pixel` callback function in order to pass data to the main function `track_ground`:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint


# mouse callback function
def get_pixel(event,x,y,flags,param):

    if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        img = param['img']
        b, g, r = img[x, y]
        # We are moving around the mouse to find the range of values for rgb
        # of the background; we will use them for thresholding later.
        
        cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        
        param['b_min'] = min(b, param['b_min'])
        param['g_min'] = min(g, param['g_min'])
        param['r_min'] = min(r, param['r_min'])
        param['b_max'] = max(b, param['b_max'])
        param['g_max'] = max(g, param['g_max'])
        param['r_max'] = max(r, param['r_max'])
        
        rgb_minmax = param.copy()
        del rgb_minmax['img']
        pprint(rgb_minmax)

def track_ground():
    
    ##########################################

    
    img = cv2.imread('data/my_image.jpg')
    cv2.namedWindow('image')
    param = {
        'img': img,
        'b_min': 255,
        'g_min': 255,
        'r_min': 255,
        'b_max': 0,
        'g_max': 0,
        'r_max': 0
    }
    cv2.setMouseCallback('image',get_pixel, param)
    while True:
        cv2.imshow('image',img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
    ###########################################
    
    print('min:', param['b_min'], param['g_min'], param['r_min'])
    print('max:', param['b_max'], param['g_max'], param['r_max'])
    
    return param
```

Is there maybe another better solution ?